# Meld not showing filenames

Tags: 20.04, meld

I used Meld 3.20.2-1ubuntu1 updated on 30/1/21 and upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 recently. Meld was working fine until recently: though there is a warning for a crash report at the beginning, Meld compares the directories indicated and issues a report but the filenames are hidden (picture below).
What is happening ? thanks for your help,

[image]

---

While executing

```
mkdir /tmp/{da,db}; echo a > /tmp/da/f; echo b > /tmp/db/f; meld /tmp/{da,db}
```

I get plenty of errors messages :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/ui/emblemcellrenderer.py", line 95, in do_render pixbuf = self._get_pixbuf(self._icon_name, self._icon_size) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/ui/emblemcellrenderer.py", line 83, in _get_pixbuf pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(name, size, 0).copy() gi.repository.GLib.Error: gtk-icon-theme-error-quark: Icon 'folder' not present in theme Adwaita (0)" several times and finishing with "cairo.Error: Context.restore() without matching Context.save()", but report correct,

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep icon-theme; export | grep DESKTOP
```

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'gnome'
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme-backup 'gnome'
com.canonical.unity-greeter icon-theme-name 'ubuntu-mono-dark'
org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Adwaita' 

declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu" 
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated" 
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="ubuntu:GNOME" 
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"
```

Comment: What is the result when you create two dirs with files and compare their contents - `mkdir /tmp/{da,db}; echo a > /tmp/da/f; echo b > /tmp/db/f; meld /tmp/{da,db}` ? Do you have any errors/warnings in the terminal?

Comment: Plenty of errors messages : "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/ui/emblemcellrenderer.py", line 95, in do_render
    pixbuf = self._get_pixbuf(self._icon_name, self._icon_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/meld/ui/emblemcellrenderer.py", line 83, in _get_pixbuf
    pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(name, size, 0).copy()
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gtk-icon-theme-error-quark: Icon 'folder' not present in theme Adwaita (0)" several times and finishing with "cairo.Error: Context.restore() without matching Context.save()", but report correct,

Comment: Seems to be theme issue. What is your current desktop? Also please add output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep icon-theme; export | grep DESKTOP` to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my problem. Desktop is an Asus ZenBook (Core i5-8250U /SSD 256G/ RAM 8G). Output of your command line is: org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme 'gnome'
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme-backup 'gnome'
com.canonical.unity-greeter icon-theme-name 'ubuntu-mono-dark'
org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Adwaita'
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="ubuntu:GNOME"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"

Answer (score 3):

I initially encountered this problem in my newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 1 and, later, in Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL 2. I'd like to share the [solution originally pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312729/meld-not-showing-filenames#comment2256554_1313239) by @logoff:

I installed the package adwaita-icon-theme-full:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

After that, meld started running fine.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue with meld (however I was trying to run it inside a docker container with X11 forwarding). My problem was that I just didn't have the icon theme on the host installed in the docker container (for me ubuntustudio-icon-theme). Meld seems to get very upset if it can't find the icons it expects.

It might be worth trying an `apt install adwaita-icon-theme` (I also noticed a adwaita-icon-theme-full package .. no idea if this is relevant for your problem though).

(I realise that my setup was likely different from yours and this might be a long shot to solve your issue, however I thought it was worth mentioning on off chance it helps and for all 3 people out there that are struggling to use meld inside docker)

Comment: Thanks @David, running     `apt install adwaita-icon-theme` just indicate that the last version is already in place; however crash report Ubuntu mix seems weird (DIstroRelease Ubuntu 20.04, InstallationMedia Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Only `adwaita-icon-theme-full` worked from me in Ubuntu 20.04 up-to-date. Why is not declared as dependency of the package? 

Comment: @logoff - just a guess, but I think `adwaita-icon-theme` is already installed on standard ubuntu desktop, but if you're running headless (docker, WSL1/2, etc.) then it wouldn't be, unless you also install a desktop like GNOME, Xcfe, LXDE/LXQT, KDE, MATE, Unity, etc.

Comment: when I wrote this, I was using Xubuntu, so XFCE was my DE. Meld is an independent program, that may work with different DE, so, if it requires a set of icons provided by a package, I guess it should require it as dependency.